# WebIDE in Firefox 48 not showing Firefox for Android

Tags: android, firefox

I have a Motorola G4 running Android 6.0.1 and want to remotely debug a website in Firefox for Android (version 48). On my Windows machine I have Firefox 48.0.2.

Both devices are connected via USB. I followed the instructions on  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging/Debugging_Firefox_for_Android_with_WebIDE.

The WebIDE in Firefox on my Windows machine never shows Firefox in the list of USB-Devices. It does show Chrome when I open it on my mobile and allows me to debug that.

Anyone any idea what could be wrong. Remotely debugging Chrome is no problem, but Firefox for Android is. I also never get prompted in Firefox for Android to allow an incoming connection.

Thx!